# What is this distribution called by?

Tags: distributions

I have pdf of a continuous distribution as below

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi x^3}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} {\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\mu \sqrt{x}} \right)}^2}$$

Is there any specific name for this distribution? Apparently it looks like a normal distribution, but it is not the case

Comment: Is this only defined for $x>0$? The $\sqrt{x}$ term in the denominator of the exponent would give you an imaginary number for $x<0$, and you would divide by zero for $x=0$. I don't think this has a name, but someone may know more.

Comment: @StephanKolassa While I have been provided with any information about the `support` of this distribution, but looking at the expression of `pdf`, it should be `X > 0` as you said.

Comment: Apart from the mentioned squared root, it looks very close to [Inverse Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution)

Answer (score 4):

[ Revised: the original question had an unfortunate \times notation that looked like an $x$. That has been removed, and the answer below now reflects the above. Notation matters! ]

The stated functional form is Inverse Gaussian with pdf:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi  x^3}} {\exp \left[-\frac{(x-\mu )^2}{2 \mu ^2 x}\right]}  \quad \quad \text{for} \quad  x> 0$$

As the OP notes, the pdf does not look like a Normal distribution and nor should it generally do so. The following diagram plots the above Inverse Gaussian when $\mu$ is 1 , 2 and 3 and contrasts with a typical Normal pdf (shown in orange):

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm confused the first form you give for $f$ doesn't quite match the form of $f$ in the question.

Comment: Hi Glen. Looks the same to me. Can you please provide more detail.

Comment: @wolfies Well, I guess in the original we have denominator $2(\mu\times\sqrt x)^2$, which maybe could be written $2\mu^2x$, while in yours you have denominator $2\mu^2x^3$. So there's an $x$ vs $x^3$ thing going on... which also appears to be the primary distinction between the "stated functional form" and the "Inverse Gaussian pdf".

Comment: You can hit "edit" to see the markup of the formula. It says: \mu \times \sqrt{x}. It's not $\mu x \sqrt{x}$, as you seem to think. It is indeed the inverse Gaussian, making this answer feel more like a gripe about how the formula is written than a good-faith answer.

Comment: Wolfies: just as Daniel says. @Jounce I'd attribute it to a simple error,  which we're all subject to. Wolfies' many, many answers show a long and  clear history of being helpful. I'd avoid attributing any lesser motive here.

Comment: I have removed the superfluous \times notation from the question that looked like an $x$ and causing all the confusion ... and all is resolved.